# ssis data flow task defaults vs dts transform data task defaults

Tags: sql-server, ssis, bids, dts, dataflow

We are converting dts packages to ssis. I have noticed that the defaults between the 2 are a little different and I'm trying to figure out what is best.

In the dts, when creating a transform data task, these were the defaults and are what we used

```
Fetch Buffer Size: 1
Insert Batch Size: 0
```

If I migrate this dts in BIDS, the new values in the SSIS data flow are

```
Rows per Batch: 1
Maximum Insert Commit Size: 0
```

Running the package gives me this warning (which definitely doesn't sound good)

```
The Maximum insert commit size property of the OLE DB destination "component "transformation" (16)" is set to 0. This property setting can cause the running package to stop responding.
```

However, if I create a new SSIS and add a data flow task, these are the defaults

```
Rows per Batch: (blank)
Maximum Insert Commit Size: 2147483647
```

Generally, the Recovery Model of the source database is Full and the Recovery Model of the destination database is Simple.  Sometimes, the task is moving up to a few million rows.

**So, in general, what is the recommended setting. And if I need to test to figure it out, what exactly should I be looking at to figure out what the best setting is?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with the following values, then increase them until they don't produce an improvement:

Rows per Batch: 100000
Maximum Insert Commit Size: 100000

I also use Lock Table whenever I can.